# Is it possible to remap Alt+F4 for Starcraft 2 running on Arch Linux?

Tags: starcraft-2, linux

I am playing Starcraft 2 on Arch Linux, using the Awesome window manager.

I'd like to remap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to the 4th camera position. As it currently works, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> tries to close the game obviously.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is not a shortcut linked to any function on Arch or Awesome, it is only Starcraft which is currently recognising it.

Comment: Does SC2 allow you to disable the alt-f4 shortcut, the way it allows you to disable alt-tab? I vaguely recall that it does but it's been awhile since I checked.

Comment: My apologize, I'm on Linux, I forgot to mention it. I know that is not officially supported but it works perfectly for me.

Comment: It would help to know which distribution and/or desktop / window manager you are using. Depending on which one you use it may be possible to change the "close window" mapping to something other than Alt+F4 (For example, KDE's Plasma uses Alt+F4 but Enlightenment uses Ctrl+Alt+X, and they can be changed).

Comment: @TwoD Mi distribution is Arch and as I said I'm using a window manager (Awesome) and ALT+F4 is not assigned to any function, I close my windows with Super+Q.

Comment: @GhostOrder, sorry, not sure why I missed that.

Comment: If you have some other key that is unused by both you and the game, you might be able to use some xmodmap command to remap F4 -> some less benign key in Linux and then map the function you want to Alt + (whatever key) in the game. You should be able to physically press Alt + F4 and have it acts as your mapping. This does assume that the game is reading virtual key codes and not raw keypresses though and that you would be ok with F4 being remapped. I think xmodmap and setxkbmap are temporary mappings. For permanent ones, see wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration

Answer (score -2):

Alt+F4 is a Windows pre-mapped combo. Like ctrl+alt+del, you can't simply remap it to a game position as the OS takes priority. Try mapping another unused OS combo.